# What dependency is missing from this Spring Boot Application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependencies

I would like to create a Spring boot Web application with H2 database and JPA support. But STS throws an error at pom.xml overview : 
Missing artifact org.springrfamework.boot:spring-boot-test.jar:1.5.6.RELASE (Click for 49 more)

Here is my pom.xml , I have no idea what's the problem.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>data-demo-CS</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried manually update maven dependencies? Right click on the project and under maven menu, select update project. Check force update of snapshots/releases option. Then build the project.

Comment: What does the "49 More" say?

Comment: Also are you able to successfully complete a `mvn clean install` via command line? Or is the error just in Eclipse's STS?

Comment: @amicoderozer Thanks! Maven update solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Actually your ide not getting the dependency, you should `clean build` again and if still showing error then simply remove that dependencies from your local  repository (I. e. ./.m2 if using maven) and `clean build` your project again then all required dependencies will be downloaded I your local.

Command `mvn clean compile package install`